# Buyer information provided by Apple to Vendor for AppStore purchases

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

Since I'm not currently selling anything in the apple appstore it would be nice if someone  who does could help me out with some details on the information Apple provides to the developer about the people purchasing your apps in the Mac/iOS Appstore. Do you get any personal information like the email address?

I'm asking this because I'm working on a multi platform SaaS solution and I'm evaluating if I the appstore(s) could be integrated into my own account management as just an alternative payment method.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provide no uniquely identifying customer information for App store app purchases to developers.  iOS Developers only get a count of the number purchases per day/week/month for each country in which the app is enabled for sale.